# how to scale MVC 4 WebApi and Entitiy Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, scalability, asp.net-web-api

I have a web app built with MVC 4 with WebApi on the back end which has entity framework.

I have used structure map to inject the entity framework to webapi. and injecting webapi client to MVC 4 app.

he application is running fine, but soon I will need scale.

MVC 4 app sits on one server, webapi is on another server and there is a database server.

How can I scale webapi horizontally? if i add webapi servers and database servers, is there a configuration for entity framework which will take multiple connection strings and do a round robin querying? is there sharding available for EF.

How about httpclient? how about failover such as client takes multiple IPs and if one fails, requests go to another server?

How can I scale them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically one adds additional web servers and then uses a load balancer to distribute incoming requests among them. There's a few considerations here.

- If the web server persists data across requests (via ASP.NET session), you will need to create a separate state server that all the web servers can share, or use a load balancer that is state aware.
- If the performance issue is stemming from database IO problems, (missing table indexes, index fragmentation, requests pulling huge result sets, less than optimal disk\hardware configs, etc...) then adding more web servers will not address the problem. The first step is to monitor and profile your database and make sure it is performing well.

Comment: i already know these. how about HttpClint or DbContext? do they take multiple connection strings and do consistent hashing, and load balancing ?

Comment: No, you should keep a single database for all the web servers. Microsoft's advice for SQL Server is always to scale up before scale out. Horizontally scaling SQL Server is extremely difficult see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181131(v=sql.105).aspx for more information. If I needed to horizontally scale a database, I would not use Microsoft SQL.

Comment: single database? is this a joke? i was in a media company where they had 30 sql servers in sync just for tracking. and which single server will handle billion transaction per day let alone sql server.

Comment: If you must horizontally scale Microsoft SQL, you will need to redesign the application to work with distributed partitioned views in mind, or find a third party application for load balancing the cluster.

Comment: AWS already provides that. likewise azure had a solution as well. however, using a single centralized database for an app that has lot of data and visitors is a terrible idea.

Comment: I am not able to understand why this is the accepted answer as it is really vague and everybody knows that we need load balancing. The real question is how do we implement it technically in Web Api instead of just theoretically?